# 1999 Sebring Jxi: coolant boiling and leaking

Tags: chrysler, coolant-leak, coolant-reservoir, sebring

I drive a 1999 Sebring Jxi convertible. About a week ago, my car overheated and puddled antifreeze. I have been keeping a close eye on it ever since. On warm days, it leaks a lot more antifreeze, but I can't find where it's coming from. I checked to see if it had leaked into the motor, but the exhaust smells fine and the oil looks okay (my dad said it would look like chocolate milk if it had).

On cooler days, I don't lose much coolant at all. I had my dad give a cursory glance and he thinks my radiator's leaking. Today, after I got to work, I heard a gurgling sound and when I raised the hood, the coolant was boiling in the reservoir and puddling under the wheel. Is this a sign of a bad thermostat too or have I blown a head gasket? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It could be either, or as simple as a faulty pressure cap, or a leak somewhere in the system.

You can replace the cap generally for pretty cheap, so that may be your first thing to try.

Sometimes the radiator core cracks loose from the radiator side tanks a bit and leaks there, which requires replacement of the radiator.

I believe that on this model you have to lift the engine to change the thermostat - it's a bigger job than most. Best check that in the service manual though.